# Minimum data transfer speed on the modern Internet?

Tags: networking, internet

Adapted from a question on another site, based on a recommendation to post it here...

The following video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4e0fRKHG7Hk&t=125s) got me thinking--what if you had an old computer that would, for example, take 5 minutes to decode a frame of modern Youtube video (doing everything in software, old processor, etc.). So provided you had the necessary software, you could watch video at 0.2 frames per minute. You realistically would probably not seek to do this, as it would presumably be like watching paint dry... but let's say you did. And so, your computer can only accept packets of video data from Google at a rate that corresponds to this decoding rate, lest your local buffer overflow. Would there be problems with this--as in, would all the computers along the way from the server to yours just slow down to accommodate?

I imagine there's some point at which data packets are requested too slowly, where computers assume the connection has gone dead and interrupt the transfer rather than keep it in progress--my question is where is that point reached? Clearly there are places in the world where people still use dialup, so there must be some tolerance for that. But how big is this tolerance?

Is the tolerance different for something like video than for text? In other words, when a server at Youtube sends you video, will it "balk" and stop sending at a cutoff rate of packet transfer that is lower than a server sending a pure text webpage?

Comment: From the [help center](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask) [emphasis mine]: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions **based on actual problems that you face**. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page." Is there any actual problem here?

Comment: I think the good answer below lets this question off on the 'actual problem' issue. Even though it's theoretical, it aids understanding of how receive window, acks etc work.

Answer (score 2):

> I imagine there's some point at which data packets are requested too slowly, where computers assume the connection has gone dead and interrupt the transfer rather than keep it in progress--my question is where is that point reached? Clearly there are places in the world where people still use dialup, so there must be some tolerance for that. But how big is this tolerance?

In most cases, as long as the packets are *acknowledged* in time (i.e. you're able to send TCP ACKs back to the server), you don't really reach that point even on the slowest connection. TCP flow control handles slow connections the same way it handles busy programs or weak systems – the "receive window" size can be shrunk as much as needed, and there's no inherent or deliberate lower limit in the transport protocols.

Specific software *may* start closing connections at some point if the effective speed is too low, but that's not universal and there's no standard "too low" either, it depends on the situation.

(Also, the modern Internet isn't just videos – there are still plenty of protocols that are basically text. Even bloated HTML/JS webpages aside, you can still send email via SMTP or use various chat apps, you can still connect to remote systems via SSH or Telnet, etc. – SSH still works even over a 9600bps serial link, although it gets a bit painful.)

> Is the tolerance different for something like video than for text? In other words, when a server at Youtube sends you video, will it "balk" and stop sending at a cutoff rate of packet transfer that is lower than a server sending a pure text webpage?

YouTube is a special case here (will get to it later).

*In general,* when you're just downloading something over HTTP, "video" doesn't automatically factor much into it – it may be different, but that depends on the server's deliberate configuration, as the server doesn't inherently know it's sending you video data, it's just serving an HTTP request either way – unless the server's admins determine that some configuration will make it behave "better" for the purposes of video-serving.

"Static" vs "real-time" (or perhaps "on-demand" vs "real-time") is probably a more important distinction. When the server is sending you a static file (even if it's a massive file) and TCP tells it that the client is currently unable to receive more (flow control), the server can just put you on hold and resume later on; it doesn't need to buffer in RAM as the file on disk is effectively the "buffer".

On the other hand, when it's sending you a live stream where data is *continuously* generated, the same TCP would require the server to buffer all data infinitely (as TCP promises reliable delivery), so at some point the server would reach its imposed per-client limit and disconnect you.

(IRC chat comes to mind as a specific example. It's all just *text* – literally a protocol from the dial-up era – but if you're connected to an IRC server and are in too many channels and users keep sending messages faster than you're receiving them, eventually the server's allocated buffer for you *will* fill up and it will close the connection with "SendQ Exceeded".)

**YouTube** is a different case from video in general. YouTube uses TCP/HTTP but the player downloads the video "on demand" in small chunks (both for streams and for recorded videos), so even a live stream works like the "static" case – there is no persistent connection that could fill up; if the player notices that downloading a chunk took too long, it switches to lower quality and can retry the same chunk if needed. If the computer can't process a chunk fast enough, the player just won't *request* the next one until it's ready.

Most other "live" things use non-TCP protocols that allow simply dropping data if it can't be delivered in time, e.g. RTP for VoIP audio/video streams instead of TCP. If the connection is slow, some packets will be dropped but the stream will carry on – but if too many are dropped, the server or client might choose to end the stream.

> would all the computers along the way from the server to yours just slow down to accommodate?

Most of them do not care at all. Transmission speed is controlled by the endpoints – it's only the sender that decides when it should send a packet to the receiver; the routers along the way either forward it or queue it or drop it but don't really "slow down" much. (Routers do *some* queuing, but they much prefer dropping excess packets than holding them.)

If a link begins dropping packets for some reason (e.g. connection too slow and the router's buffer fills up to the point of dropping packets), the sender will notice the lack of acknowledgements and its "flow control" and "congestion control" algorithms will cause it to slow down transmission. This is already happening *all the time* – servers with 10Gbps links adapt to clients with 10Mbps links, or a download over a 1Gbps link adapts to `wget` only being able to write data at 1MB/s to a cheapo flash drive.

In other words, on the Internet, *the sender* slows down accommodate both the receiver and the intermediate routers (i.e. it accommodates *all* slower or congested links along the way to the receiver).

Comment: Good answer. One more thing comes to mind: a firewall or similar connection-tracking device can, when overloaded, drop the least recently used connections. Usually they are improperly closed connections (e.g. "the user closed the laptop lid, put the laptop in a bag and walked out" variety) but if your connection is much slower than other users of the overloaded firewall, it might end up in the least-recently-used slot and be dropped.

Comment: Possibly; I believe Linux netfilter/conntrack (the usual base for most cheap wifi routers) stops accepting new entries rather than discarding old ones, but I don't know how other systems behave.